# expected ';' at end of declaration - reaplacing a struct member dot operator

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors

I'm writing a simple liars dice game. Unfortunately, i get a problem when I compile, saying there should be a ';' and pointing to the dot operator on a struct located in one of my functions.

```
error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    struct player p1.dice[i] = ((rand() % 6) + 1);
                    ^
                    ;
```

I've tried different types of declaring the struct but to no avail. Is this a problem with using an array?

```
/Global Variables
int amountCall;
int diceCall;
int fails;
int dice[STARTINGDICE];

//Prototypes
int diceRoll();
void playerTurn();
int playerCreator();
int diceDisplay();

typedef struct 
{
    int fails;
    int dice[STARTINGDICE];
    int amountCall;
    int diceCall;    
} 
player;

player p1;
player p2;

int diceRoll()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < (STARTINGDICE - fails); i++)
    {
        player p1.dice[i] = ((rand() % 6) + 1);                <<---- Error
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
player p1.dice[i] = ((rand() % 6) + 1);
```

to

```
p1.dice[i] = ((rand() % 6) + 1);
```